Response SOAP Request
I'm using cURL to make an HTTP POST request to a zimbra SOAP server and get auth token, but I'm getting the HTML page instead of the SOAP response. What I'm doing wrong?
That's the code
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:zimbraAccount">
        <soap:Header>
            <context xmlns="urn:zimbra"/>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <AuthRequest xmlns="urn:zimbraAccount">
            <account by="name">{$username}</account>
            <password>{$password}</password>
            </AuthRequest>
        </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
        EOD;

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->zimbraSoapUrl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapXml);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/soap+xml']);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            $errorMessage = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            throw new \Exception("Erro cURL: $errorMessage");
        }
        

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        return $response;


Why don't you use the SoapClient? It also capable of auth methods. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient

This is likely a case of needing to send the right HTTP headers.
Firstly, you've specified Content-Type, which indicates the type of data you are sending, but not Accept, which indicates the type of data you want to receive (see MDN documentation for Accept).
Secondly, SOAP requests are generally required to include a SOAPAction header, whose value is defined by the service, and often needs to match the particular method you're calling on the API. There is no standard for the format of this header, other than that it should be a URL, so you will need to find the right values in the API documentation, or in a machine-readable WSDL specification file.
Thirdly, some SOAP services use extra HTTP headers, to perform tasks like authentication outside of the SOAP system. Check the documentation carefully, and bear in mind that SOAP is often used with dedicated client libraries which discover a lot of settings using WSDL configuration, rather than building the XML and HTTP requests by hand.
It's worth noting that PHP does have a SoapClient class, and you may find that is easier than working directly with CURL; however, SOAP services vary a lot, so it may not have all features you need, or may not be straight-forward to configure.
